# Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I am currently trying to run Android simulator with Expo for the first time ever and I am encountering a build failure when trying to run my application using `npx expo run:android`. The error seems to be originating from the react-native-reanimated module. I have followed steps from the official expo docs on how to setup the emulator.

Initially, I was receiving 2 errors:

1. Error indicating that Java was missing, so I installed Java from the official Java website.
2. After that, I encountered a JDK-related error, so I installed JDK 21 from the Oracle website.

The 3rd and current error message I receive when running `npx expo run:android` is:

```
> Task :react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-reanimated:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-reanimated:androidJdkImage'.
   > Failed to transform core-for-system-modules.jar to match attributes {artifactType=_internal_android_jdk_image, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for JdkImageTransform: /Users/adam/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-34/core-for-system-modules.jar.
         > Error while executing process /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jlink with arguments {--module-path /Users/adam/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4b1308f73665eeac924c132c45e496df/transformed/output/temp/jmod --add-modules java.base --output /Users/adam/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4b1308f73665eeac924c132c45e496df/transformed/output/jdkImage --disable-plugin system-modules}

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.3/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

BUILD FAILED in 17s
```

I have `"react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2"` installed.

Unfortunately I haven't been able to solve this one and would like to ask you for help on how this can be solved.

Comment: What is your react native version?
also share your react-native.config.js for better understanding of issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per react native official documentation, React-Native recommend JDK 17.

`If you have already installed JDK on your system, we recommend JDK 17. You may encounter problems using higher JDK versions.`

Follow [Setting up the development environment](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup?platform=android)

It may fix your build issue.